# adding multiple sidebars on pages

Tags: themes, widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I am using twentyten theme and I want there to be two sidebars on my page - one on the  left and the second on the right.
Can any one tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thirty Ten](http://aaron.jorb.in/thirtyten/) is a child theme of Twenty Ten and could be excellent for you as it comes with 3 columns as you want.

Comment: hey bro..thanks it helped me out.So one up vote from me...

Comment: glad I could help you!

Answer (score 2):

There's more information about custom theme modification to add sidebars on another thread [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/798/is-there-possibility-to-customize-the-present-theme-adding-sidebars)

The link is potintig to the tutorial [here](http://www.balkhis.com/web-designs-resources/how-to-add-a-dynamic-sidebar-in-wordpress/) which I found quite useful, that basically tells you to change functions.php so register_sidebars creates the number of sidebars you want

From:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebars') )
    register_sidebar();
```

To:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebars') ) {
    register_sidebar('2');
    register_sidebar('3');
    register_sidebar('4');
}
```

Comment: Add at least a summary. An answer should be [more than just some links](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).